# Using a global translation object in express JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, internationalization

I've built a very simple translation module for Express JS, it's a global object in the application scope that's instantiated at application runtime:

```
translator.configure({
    translations: 'translations.json'
});
```

I've added some simple middleware to Express JS that changes the locale in the translator module for each request:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var locale = // Get locale from request host header

    // Setup the translator
    translator.setLocale(locale);

    // Attach translator to request parameters
    res.locals.__ = translator.translations;

    // Pass control to the next middleware function
    next();
});
```

Then I access my translations through the variable `__` in my views (here I use ejs):

```
...
Here is my translated text: <%= __['test'] %>
...
```

My translator module looks like this:

```
var translations,
    locale;

// public exports
var translator = exports;

translator.configure = function(opt) {
    translations = require('./' + opt.translations);
};

translator.setLocale = function(locale) {
    translator.translations = translations[locale];
}
```

The translations.json file is just a simple JSON structure:

```
{
    "us":{
        "test": "Hello!"
    },
    "es":{
        "test": "Hola!"
    }
}
```

My question is, is this overall structure a bad idea? I do not have extensive knowledge about express JS. The global object makes me kind of nervous since the translations are based of its current state, which is changed from request to request, any problems here? Does express JS fully complete a request before handling the next one, or is there some level of concurrency going on that can mess up my translations?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node

Comment: @stdob-- Thanks, but that's basically the module I based my own code on. I  thought the module looked like overkill for my purpose, and I needed something that had more flexibility than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global object is a bad idea for saving state that is used during a request.  A request is not necessarily completed before the next one starts running.  If, at any time, a request handler makes an asynchronous call (like to read a file), then another request can start running at that point.

In general, you should store state related to a specific request on the request object itself.  That way, it is not global and is stored specifically for that request only and you can have as many requests going at once without conflict.

So, you could ideally not store any request-specific state in your translator object at all unless you create a new translator object for each request and then store that specific translator object in the request object.

I don't follow your translator code exactly, but this looks like trouble:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var locale = // Get locale from request host header

    // Setup the translator
    translator.setLocale(locale);

    // Attach translator to request parameters
    res.locals.__ = translator.translations;

    // Pass control to the next middleware function
    next();
});
```

Because it looks like you're configuring a shared, global translator object, then expecting to use it later and expecting it not to be changed by any other request.  That seems like asking for trouble.

If your request handler makes any async call at any point, then another request handler can run which can create a conflict as both try to use the same translator object.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the scenario I feared, so I will try to get around that issue.